# After clicking 'submit', I want to be redirected back to the same page, using a relative path

Tags: php, html, xml, redirect, http-headers

This is part of a  `simpleXML` parser in php ;

```
if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit'])) {
    header('Location: http://wft.com/customerentry.php');
}
```

The problem is this is going to be on several servers so I need a relative path `customerentry.php`, and I forgot how that's done...

Comment: Just remove the domain name .. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit']))
{
    header('Location: customerentry.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `header("Location: http:/relative/path");`

In your code, it should be

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit'])){
    header('Location: http:/customerentry.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a part relative to the current path, you can just do this :

```
if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit'])) {
    header('Location: customerentry.php');
}
```

If you want a part relative to the root of your site, start your URL with a `/` :

```
if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit'])) {
    header('Location: /customerentry.php');
}
```

---

#### Note :

Even though using relative browsers is supported, the actual [**HTTP/1.1 RFC**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) explicitly states that the URL given in the `Location` header should always be absolute, and not relative. Therefore, it's best to always use absolute URLs, like this :

```
var $basePath = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $basePath . '/customerentry.php');
}
```